# Is it possible to build a Go binary using the standard library?

Tags: go

Having studied the source code I don't think it's possible, but can a Go binary be built using something like:

```
import "package/from/stdlib"

func main() {
    ...
    stdlib.BuildBinary(path)
    ...
}
```

https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/cmd/go/main.go
https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/cmd/go/internal/work/build.go

(I'm trying to simplify a build stage in a CI pipeline)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the standard lib does not contain the compiler's (source) code. The compiler's source is available here: https://github.com/golang/go/tree/release-branch.go1.20/src/cmd/compile

But if you have the standard lib, that should be part of a Go installation, which contains the Go tool, giving you cross-compilation support. So in short: all you need is the (official) Go installation. Call the `go` tool as an external command if you want to compile source code into an executable binary.

Note however that even though the standard lib does not contain the compiler and linker's code, you can use the standard lib to parse Go sources. See the [`go/ast`](https://pkg.go.dev/go/ast) and [`go/parser`](https://pkg.go.dev/go/parser) packages.